# Gravity Forms - Custom Merge Tag Convert date_created to Local/WordPress Time?

Tags: functions, plugin-gravity-forms

I create a number of custom merge tags on my forms, one of which is "Date Submitted" which references the Gravity Form 'date_created' property as seen here https://docs.gravityforms.com/entry-date-merge-tags/

But the date/time is always returned as UTC time. I'd like to convert it to the timezone set on the WordPress settings. This is the code I'm using to generate the custom date_submitted field:

```
'{date_submitted}' => date( 'l, F j, Y \a\t g:i A', strtotime( $entry['date_created'] ) ),
```

I found the original code here https://snippet.farm/code/custom-merge-tags/

Comment: Sorry, but third party plugins (like Gravity Forms) are off topic here.

Comment: If your question were not about Gravity, but more like "how can I convert UTC timestamp of format X to a date string win WP's timezone?", the answer could probably rely on [`wp_timezone()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone/) together with [`DateTime::createFormFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).